# Getting error while enable www. from Drupal 8 .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, drupal-8, no-www

**Error:**

This page isn’t working.

www.example.com redirected you too many times.

**.htaccess**

```
# If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
# can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
# URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/foo will be redirected to http://www.example.com/foo)
# uncomment the following:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The site is using https:// and it's a single site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

this could perhaps help you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```